# How to redirect to a specific page on successful sign up using rails devise gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

How to redirect to a specific page on successful sign up using rails devise gem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This page is for you: http://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in

Comment: Yannis, you misunderstood my question. It was about sign UP not sign IN.

Comment: where you able to make it work ? because somehow it never seems to go through my overridden controller... Do I need to update my routes ? If I do so then I need to have another of views ?

Answer (score 2):

I hope its not too late, you need to override the after_sign_up_path_for of the registration controller, create a registrations_controller.rb in your app/controller, and override said action.

registrations_controller.rb

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    ...path of choice...
  end

end
```

haven't tested this code so might not work with just copy and paste.
If you look here it will give you the actions for any other redirects you made need.

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb

Answer (score 0):

The wiki page recently moved and the info is here:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in-and-sign-out