# Can I execute custom actions after successful sign in with Devise?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have an app that has basic Devise authentication.  After sign in, I would like to look up the user account (user belongs_to account, account has_many users), and store that in the session so that it is available like the `@current_user`.

What is the rails way of storing session in formation like this?
Is there a hook I can use with Devise to execute code after successful sign-in?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

*Edit*: Please consider that this was once a good solution, but there are probably better ways of handling this. I am only leaving it here to give people another option and to preserve history, please do not downvote.

Yes, you can do this. The first resource I'd look at is http://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in. Also, check out [How to redirect to a specific page on successful sign up using rails devise gem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881093/how-to-redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-up-using-rails-devise-gem) for some ideas.

You can do something like:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
  session[:my_account] = current_user.account
  profile_url
end
```

You can implement this method in your ApplicationController or in a custom RegistrationsController.

Comment: [This](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/DatabaseAuthenticatable#after_database_authentication-instance_method) seems a less hacky way.

Comment: This was answered in 2011 and was the accepted solution at the time. Thanks for the update on another method.

Answer (score 39):

Actually, the accepted answer does not work properly in case of combined Omniauth and Database login modules in Devise.

The native hook that is executed after every successfull sign in action in Devise (disregarding the user authentication channel) is warden.set_user (called by devise *sign_in* helper: http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/Controllers/SignInOut#sign_in-instance_method).

In order to execute custom action after successfull user sign in (according to Warden Docs: https://github.com/hassox/warden/wiki/Callbacks), put this into initializer (eg. *after_sign_in.rb* in *config/initializers*)

```
Warden::Manager.after_set_user except: :fetch do |user, auth, opts|
  #your custom code
end
```

**Update 2015-04-30**: Thanks to @seanlinsley suggestion (see comments below),  I have corrected the answer to include *except: :fetch* in order to trigger the callback only when user is authenticated and not every time it is set.

**Update 2018-12-27** Thanks to @thesecretmaster for pointing out that Warden now has built-in callbacks for executing your own code on *after_authentication* https://github.com/wardencommunity/warden/wiki/Callbacks#after_authentication

Comment: It turns out `after_set_user` is called whenever the user is set, not whenever the user is authenticated, which happens at least once per request. It looks like `after_authentication` would be the more appropriate callback.

Comment: Looks like for some reason Devise doesn't trigger `after_authentication`. Devise's own source code does `after_set_user except: :fetch` instead: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/66db52ce31b5d8629f5813a1d7f03a8bc17e5d52/lib/devise/hooks/lockable.rb#L3

Comment: Thank you @seanlinsley for the throught investigation! Indeed, the after_set_user except: :fetch works best! I have corrected the answer according to your findings.

Comment: Sounds good but feels akward to write this code in an initializer. Ain't there a way out of this in a `after_filter` from `Devise::RegistrationsController`, while being able to access `current_user`?

Comment: It seems like the official "right" answer would be to use [`Warder::Manager.after_authentication`](https://github.com/wardencommunity/warden/wiki/Callbacks#after_authentication)

Comment: Good point, @thesecretmaster! Those callbacks were not available back in 2014. I will update the answer to include a link to the Warden callback docs. Thx!

Answer (score 12):

i'm using rails 5 and devise 4.2.1, my solution is overide devise function on user model:

```
def after_database_authentication
    # here's the custom code
end
```

and the user model will look like this:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
        :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
        :timeoutable, :lockable
    def after_database_authentication
        # here's the custom code
    end
end
```

it was called just after the authentication,
i read it from this [devise documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/DatabaseAuthenticatable#after_database_authentication-instance_method), hope this could help

Comment: And for sign out is there any?

Comment: @SebastianVîrlan i use this on the user model Warden::Manager.before_logout do |user,auth,opts| Your code end

Comment: In the model I create a method? Can you show me an example?

Comment: no, it's like you are use the hook of warden, this comment section was only one line, so i can't give you example clearly, maybe you could create new question, let me know when you're done create it, i'll answer it on the answer section

Answer (score 6):

I resolved this problem by overriding the `create` method of the session controller like following

```
class Admin::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

   def create 
     super
     # here goes my code
     # my settings, etc 
     # do something with current_admin.fullname, for example
  end 
end
```

In other words, if authentication is successful (by calling `super`) then I perform my settings.

Comment: This does not work as that controller action is expecting a page to be rendered as the last return

Comment: @theartofbeing Please read the question in the OP carefully. It says "Is there a hook I can use with Devise to execute code after successful sign-in?" In other words the author wants to run some code after successful sign-in. The fact every controller needs a page to render is a very BASIC fact in Rails programming and I think the author is well aware of this fact. Also, why are you 100% sure that I don't have a template `create.js` or `create.html.erb`? Again, the issue is not about what to render or not.

Comment: I guess I interpreted it as wanting to call a method when authentication/sign in is successful, and then continuing with the `create` method. In other words, I might want to update an attribute on the user after I **know** the sign in was successful, while still leaving the functionality of the devise method in-tact (i.e. rendering some template)

Answer (score 0):

In application controller, you can simply add an after action.

*app/controllers/users/application_controller.rb*

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  after_action :do_something

  def do_something
    # do something
  end
end
```