# Post devise login info to zapier

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, zapier

Has anyone had experience in sending user data to zapier after login with devise?

After plenty of research i haven't found something that'd post the users email address to a webhook.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking. What data do you want to send? Is it to a specific webhook or what?

Answer (score 0):

post to zapier using httpParty:

`HTTParty.post(ENV['ZAPIER_CANDIDATE_UPDATED_URL'], body: notification_body)`

use webhook integration @ zapier and consume `notification_body` hash with `email` inside

Where to fire up this code in devise? Take a look: [Ruby on Rails Devise code after login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21268559/ruby-on-rails-devise-code-after-login)