# Do something in a controller immediately following Devise sign up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

When a user signs up with Devise, I want to check if their email address contains `@mysite.com`, and if so, create a new record in a table with the new user's ID.

I've been looking through the Devise docs for a way to take action after a user signs up (since I need their ID for associations), but all I've found is `after_sign_up_path_for` which is just a path.

Any ideas?

```
 class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
   def create
     super

     # I was hoping "super" creates the new user, and now I would have access to current_user.id, but that doesn't appear to be true.
   end
 end
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I execute custom actions after successful sign in with Devise?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753730/can-i-execute-custom-actions-after-successful-sign-in-with-devise)

Comment: I don't want to define my own redirect path. If there is a way to use their solution without overriding the redirect path, then yes their solution would work.

Comment: Couldn't you just use call `super` after the end of `after_sign_up_path_for`? Or will that not work?

Answer (score 2):

If you need to execute a function after the user logs in, Devise provides an `after_database_authentication` callback method. You would use the callback in the user model, not in the controller, with the advantage that you don't have to override the Devise Registrations controller.

See the [documentation](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/DatabaseAuthenticatable#after_database_authentication-instance_method) for DatabaseAuthenticatable.

I cover some similar techniques in my [Rails Devise Tutorial](http://railsapps.github.io/rails-devise/), but in the tutorial I only mention the `after_database_authentication` callback method in passing to point out that it's not necessary to override the Devise Registrations controller to accommodate a post-sign-up action.

Comment: Wow thanks so much! I have been searching for a good solution, and finally I have found one! :)

Answer (score 0):

I copied the following structure from one of my applications:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  after_filter :do_something, only: :create

  def create
    ...

    super

    ...
  end

  def do_something
    # User succesfully created?
    return unless @user.id

    ... @user.id
  end
end
```