# How to select one yaml file from a group of yaml files in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, yaml

I want to be able to select a yaml file inside a folder called market. This folder will be in config/market. Inside this folder I will have many yaml files, for example:

```
  config/market
        usa.yml
        cad.yml
        eur.yml
```

Inside each yml file I will have same variables but different default values. for example on usa.yml

```
    ---
    :usa
      country: "United States"
      currency: "USD"
```

For eur.yml,

```
    ---
    :eur
     country: "European Union"
     currency: "EUR"
```

and so on. I want to use country and currency as global variables for example in my rails app. Depending on user location I will select the yaml file.

I want to select only one yaml file from the market folder when the user login in my application. Maybe do a before_action call in the application controller. Something like this

```
 before_action :set_market

 private
   def set_market
     if (statement)
      Config[:market] = :usa
     end
   end
```

How can I do this? Please any feedback will help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the YAML class to open the file.
Look this link:
https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.3/libdoc/yaml/rdoc/YAML.html

Something like this:

```
CONFIG = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root.to_s}/config/market/usa.yml")
CONFIG["usa"]
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I forgot, you need to use this require:
`require 'yaml'`

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the [MarcusVinnicius' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51933003/823321):

I would suggest using one yaml file with different market/zones. Let's assume you are using something like Spree for your market place which uses zones.

E.g.

**1. Create a yaml file (settings.yml):**

```
 production:
    united_kingdom:
      countries: ["GB", "IE"]
      currency: GBP
      //shipping ....
      //etc      
    united_states:
      countries: ["US", "PR"]
      currency:  USD
 development:
    united_kingdom:
      countries: ["GB", "IE", "test"]
      currency: GBP
      //shipping ....
      //etc      
    united_states:
      countries: ["US", "PR", "test"]
      currency:  USD
```

**2. Load the yaml file**

As in the previous answer, on a controller action.

-OR-

**Do something similar to [this](https://coderwall.com/p/8ruh8a/custom-config-for-rails-app)**

1. Create the initializer `config/initializers/load_config.rb` with:

   ```
   CONFIG_PATH="#{Rails.root}/config/settings.yml"
   APP_CONFIG = YAML.load_file(CONFIG_PATH)[Rails.env]
   ```
2. Use `before_filter` or `after_sign_in/sign_up`: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753730/can-i-execute-custom-actions-after-successful-sign-in-with-devise) to do something like this:

   before_filter: set_market_spree_zone

   ```
   def set_market_spree_zone
       market = current_user.market 
       #or if you only have the user country do something like: get_zone_from_country(current_user.country)
       #convert to abrevation united_stated to us or vice-versa as needed
       @zone = APP_CONFIG['market']
       #then use @zone for Spree or whatever you need to set globally #in the APP

   end
   ```

(This could also be after_sign_in on device or overriding the create method of the session controller)

Let me know if that works.