# Set a session variable in devise on sign in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'd like to set a session variable once a user signs in based on a certain field in the User table. I don't want to have to create a custom Devise controller if I don't have to. Is there a way? Or will I have to go the custom controller route?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is a callback [after_sign_in_path_for](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in), you can add it in your `ApplicationController`

```
protected

def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  session[:domain_prefix] = current_user.domain_prefix
  user_path(resource)
end
```

Dont forget return the path in the last line of method, otherwise the callback will redirect the request to content of `session[:domain_prefix]`

Comment: He is asking for adding a new session variable on login for ex:  keeping user's name in session. {My example is totally useless but i think this is what he wants}

Comment: Thanks, this should definitely work. I can't seem to figure out the default path is to put at the last line... I'd like to to behave as normal in that regard.

Answer (score 6):

How about this one:

The first resource I'd look at is http://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in. Also, check out [How to redirect to a specific page on successful sign up using rails devise gem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881093/how-to-redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-up-using-rails-devise-gem) for some ideas.

You can do something like:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
  session[:account_type] = current_user.account_type

end
```

You can implement this method in your ApplicationController or in a custom RegistrationsController.