# How to set a session variable after sign in with Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm trying to find out where to set a session variable once a user has logged in using Devise. I found this post (and others):

[Set a session variable in devise on sign in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7422910/set-a-session-variable-in-devise-on-sign-in)

So I tried something like this:

```
protected
    # when a user logs in
    def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
      session[:current_account_id] = current_user.accounts.find_by_is_default(true).id # get id of row where it's is_default is set as true
      abort(session[:current_account_id])
    end
```

..but no joy. I don't want to do an alternative redirect (as the issue in the link was asking), just set a session variable when the user logs in, so I'm not sure if this is the callback I'm wanting. Also, I may have my find_by_ method wrong but I was hoping I could debug (using abort) once the script gets that far - but it doesn't appear to be as abort doesn't seem to be called. Any help much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the protected method is located inside of ApplicationController.